# Static function access in c++

Tags: c++

I have a class with private static member variable and static function used to access the private static variable.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class staticMem
{
  private:
  static int myval;

 public:

 static int getmyval()
  {
  return myval;
 }

  //static void setmyval(int a)
 //{
  //myval=a;
 //}

};

int staticMem::myval =10;

int main()
{
  int x;
  //staticMem::setmyval(10);
  cout<<"the value is"<<staticMem::getmyval()<<endl;
  cin>>x;

}
```

It works perfectly.
But i want to set the value using the static function.I tried this but it wont work.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class staticMem
{
  private:
  static int myval;

 public:

 static int getmyval()
  {
  return myval;
 }

 static void setmyval(int a)
 {
  myval=a;
 }

};


int main()
{

  staticMem::setmyval(10);
  cout<<"the value is"<<staticMem::getmyval()<<endl;

}
```

**Edit**
sorry i gave the wrong question..its updated please check

Comment: What do you expect exactly ? You call `staticMem::setmyval(10);` so the value will still be 10 after the call

Comment: what a useless question.

Comment: Perhaps you could expand a little on the "it wont work".

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't work in the same way that [this one](http://ideone.com/WR8h5L) doesn't work?

Comment: Your `cin` call is only setting the local variable `x`. If you want it to set `myval` you need to follow the `cin` line with `staticMem::setmyval(x);`.

Comment: The second version doesn't actually *define* `staticMem::myval`, but merely *declares* it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static members need to be defined, so at least you need the following line after the class' declaration:

```
int staticMem::myval;
```

Comment: So we cannot provide value to static member by ourself in the first place.

Comment: I would like to add to this that you need to do that in a source file and not in the header. It is also typically a good idea to initialize the variable.